# Append selected <option> into <input> text in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to append `value` from the selected option to `input`. The option in `<select>` is from looping. So whenever I try to append the value somehow I always get the last record from the select option, not the one I have chosen.

Here is my code:

```
 $('select[name="service"]').empty();
   $.each(data, function(key, value) {
     $.each(value.costs, function(key1, value1) {
      $.each(value1.cost, function(key2, value2) {
       $('select[name="service"]').append('<option value="' +
         key + '">' + value1.service + ' - ' + value1.description + ' - ' +
         value2.value +'</option>');

         // I want to append the value2.value from selected option into this, but I always got the last record
         $('input[name="cost"]').val(value2.value);
       });
     });
   });
```

I want to append the value from the selected option to this, but I always got the last record from the loop.

Comment: what is the value inside `data`

Comment: @FaeemazazBhanej like this: https://pastebin.com/WxZCV0JJ .sorry I can't paste it here because it's to long

Comment: If you can add data in textbox it always iterate last value. you need to store it in `<span>` or `<div>`

Comment: "*I want to append the value from the selected option*"  1) Do you want to *append* the values, so that the result is a long string of all values combined?  Or just *set* the value to a single value?  2) Which value is selected?  The code builds a `<select>`, but does not set any one of the element selected?